# How to get only Numbers from a string and store it in an Array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a string that contains a mix of characters and numbers. I want to separate out the numbers from the string and store them in an Array.
So far I have been able to separate the strings and numbers and put them in Array and then able to get only numbers but the string type data is NaN.  I am unable to get rid of NaN values from the Array.

So far my code looks like this:

```
arrayList = "abcd_456_yasdb_382_h_83_2";
new_arrayList = arrayList.split('_');
console.log(new_arrayList); // Output : [ 'abcd', '456', 'yasdb', '382', 'h', '83', '2' ]


new_arrayList = new_arrayList.map(Number);
console.log(new_arrayList); // Output :  [ NaN, 456, NaN, 382, NaN, 83, 2 ]

onlyNumArray = []

for(i =0; i<new_arrayList.length; i++) {
    // console.log(new_arrayList[i]);
    if(typeof (new_arrayList[i]) === "number" && typeof(new_arrayList[i]) != NaN) {
        onlyNumArray.push(new_arrayList[i])
    }
    else {
        console.log("Not a number")
    }
}
console.log(onlyNumArray)  // Output : [ NaN, 456, NaN, 382, NaN, 83, 2 ]

Output = [ NaN, 456, NaN, 382, NaN, 83, 2 ]
Expected Output = [456, 382,83,2]
```

Comment: `typeof NaN` returns 'number', so you'll want to replace that condition with `!isNaN(new_arrayList[i])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)? Also, you can't check for `NaN` by equality (except that `NaN != NaN` as [Passerby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/570812/passerby) points out). You have to use [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) (or [`Number#isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)).

```js
const input = 'abcd_456_yasdb_382_h_83_2';

const tokens = input
  .split('_')
  .map(Number)
  .filter(i => !isNaN(i));

console.log(tokens);
```

Comment: Beat me for a minute :) Technically you can check `NaN` by equality: `.filter((i)=>{return i==i;})` can do the trick too.

Comment: True, I hadn't considered checking for the absence of self-equality. Not sure I'd immediately pick up on what was being checked if I came across it in someone else's code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `array.filter()` method and do something like this :

```
const unfilteredArray = [ NaN, 456, NaN, 382, NaN, 83, 2 ]
const numbersArray = unfilteredArray.filter(Number)
// Output : [ 456, 382, 83, 2 ]
```

Comment: `.filter(Number)` could be problematic when `0` is involved: `[83,2,0].filter(Number)` -> `[83,2]`

Answer (score 0):

```
const newArrayList = arrayList.split('_').filter(element => {
  return Number.parseInt(element);
}).map(element => {
  return Number.parseInt(element)
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
input = 'abcd_456_yasdb_382_h_83_2';
array = [...input.matchAll(/\d+/g)].map(a => parseInt(a[0]));

console.log(array); // [456, 382, 83, 2]
```

Explanation:

1. matchAll returns an array of all the regex matches. in our case, it matches sequence of number(s) and return them in an array
2. The array returned contains [extra elements in it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll#return_value). The first element is the actual matched string. So we must run a .map against our returned array, and convert the first value (our number string) into an int with parseInt

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.